# Continue for loop iteration with onClickListener in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a multiple choice quiz application, and what I'm trying to accomplish is having my "Next Question" button get values from an array in which my questions/answers are stored. The code I have so far loops through the first question, [0][0] etc. as well as the second question stored at [1][0] etc. I have 10 questions stored in my array, and I'm trying to loop through all of them. What should I change in this code to make that happen?

```
  public void addListenerOnButton(){                                                         

 Button nextQButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextQButton);                            

  nextQButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                                  

      @Override                                                                           
      public void onClick(View v) {                                                       

         for(int i = 0; i < qAndA.length; i++) {                                          
          TextView questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionText);             
          questionText.setText(qAndA[i][0]);                                              
          RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);       
          radioButton1.setText(qAndA[i][1]);                                              
          RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);       
          radioButton2.setText(qAndA[i][2]);                                              
          RadioButton radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);       
          radioButton3.setText(qAndA[i][3]);                                              
          RadioButton radioButton4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);       
          radioButton4.setText(qAndA[i][4]);                                              

       }                                                                                   

      }                                                                                   

  });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no need for a for loop here. Why not just have a counter which increments every time the button is clicked?

```
int count = 0;
```

Your onClick method could look something like this.

```
questionText.setText(qAndA[i][count]);
count++;
```

Comment: I clearly need to stop over-complicating my code. Works just the way I needed, thanks a lot!

Comment: Wasn't able to right away due to the speed of your answer haha, done! Thanks again.